# Import backup registry on windows startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, windows-registry

Is there a way to import a backed up registry into windows if it does not start after using a registry cleanup service?

Comment: in .REG format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things you can try if you have a corrupted registry:

1. **Last Known Good Configuration** from the F8 boot menu or **System Restore** from the DVD.
2. A repair install.
3. Booting from a BartPE or WinPE disc/USB, running Regedit, [loading the hive files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732157.aspx) (see default locations for Win95-XP [here](http://www.easydesksoftware.com/regfiles.htm) and Vista+ [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/where-are-the-windows-registry-files-located-in-windows-7)) and importing your .REGs *might* work.
4. Copying the hive backups located in **windows\repair** and overwriting the corrupt files in **windows\system32\config** ([XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545)), or from **windows\system32\config\regback** to **windows\system32\config** (Vista+) *might* also work.

   User-specific settings would be in **Documents and Settings\*UserName*\NTUser.dat** (XP) or **Users\*UserName*\NTUser.dat** (Vista+), if you have those backed up as well.